# What are appropriate action types in react.js?

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux

In the Flux examples, the two action types I noticed are view actions & server actions.  Are there any other action types to be concerned about from a large app perspective?  I'm just thinking of appropriate patterns to use for the long term.

https://github.com/facebook/flux/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actions are just actions.  If there's an action you use when getting the current user from the server, you could also create that action some other time (such as getting the user from local storage, etc.).

The two most common sources of events are from the UI and the server, however you could also have actions triggered on a timer (setInterval) or from a global event handler (e.g. window's resize), or third party libraries which get it from any source.

Perhaps a better word for and 'action' in flux would be an 'intent'.  It doesn't actually do anything on its own, it just suggests something be done; the dispatcher dispatches the intent, and stores can do something (i.e. take action) based on the intent.

"view actions & server actions" is either too specific or too vague.  You should either consider all actions equal (my personal take), or consider there to be hundreds of action types.

> I'm just thinking of appropriate patterns to use for the long term.

I don't quite see how classifying actions affects patterns you use.  Grouping of actions is more about which ones you want to generally expose to which other modules.  For example ChatServerActionCreators is only used by utils/ChatWebAPIUtils.  It's a matter of encapsulation rather than grouping by related functionality.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I was also indirectly asking why these event sources exist.  Your answer of considering all actions equal resonates with me, but maybe FB has some legitimate use for it aside from being an additional descriptor.

Answer (score 2):

> Thanks, I suppose I was also indirectly asking why these event sources
>   exist.

Also there is [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/pZYYbyOHKCs) on google forums answered by Bill Fisher from FB:

> Q: The todo-list example mentions a possible handleServerAction in
>   addition to handleViewAction - can someone give some color as to why
>   you might want to handle server actions differently from view actions?
>   I'm guessing a server action is triggered through polling, sockets, or
>   some external event, but is there a common case/example where it's
>   useful to check between the two types of actions? Just curious here,
>   as nothing obvious jumped out (i.e. marking an item as a favorite
>   should trigger the same codepath, regardless of where it came from).
>
> A: As far as the server actions vs. the view actions goes, I think it's
>   more common to detect a view action and act differently upon it.  For
>   example, you might want to only run a validation when the data comes
>   from user input, rather than on server initialization.  I left that in
>   there just to show that you can do whatever you want with the payload,
>   that there can be this kind of structure providing metadata around the
>   Action, allowing you to group different actions together for whatever
>   purpose you need.  You don't have to use these handleViewAction or
>   handleServerAction or handleServerInitializationAction (etc) methods,
>   but I've found it to be occasionally useful.